# How can you get a Form object from the desktop's handle?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, desktop, hwnd

I want to know if it is possible to acquire the desktop's Form. I have tried to get the hWnd from the desktop and use Form.FromHandle to get the form. But it always returns null. So I assume this is not possible; if it is possible can someone show me an example code.
Here is the code that did not work below:

```
 hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
 desktop = Form.FromHandle(hWnd) as Form;
 System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

P.S. Can someone also explain what I did wrong here.

Comment: What makes you think the desktop has a form? Only windows in your process have forms.

Comment: My answer indicates why you're seeing this behaviour. Is there a particular reason you want the desktop window as a `Form`? We might be able to help with the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this because the desktop window *isn't a `Form`*. `FromHandle()` tries to find the managed `Control` (in this case a `Form`) that corresponds to the given window handle. Since no such `Control` exists, it returns `null`.

Comment: I understand know. I always thought a desktop was considered a window.

Comment: It's *definitely* a window. But being a window doesn't mean it's a `Form`. `Form`s are a managed abstraction around unmanaged windows. So all `Form`s are (at some level) windows, but *not all windows are `Form`s*.